# Insert requirement in HP ALM with REST API and c#

Tags: c#, rest, alm

I have a code in c#, but I get the next error: "(400) incorrect request".

```
HttpWebRequest myWebRequest2 = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://myURL/qcbin/rest/domains/DEFAULT/projects/Mercury/requirements");
            myWebRequest2.Method = "POST";
            myWebRequest2.Accept = "application/json";
            myWebRequest2.ContentType = "application/json";

            myWebRequest2.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
            myWebRequest2.CookieContainer.Add(webResponse.Cookies[0]);
            myWebRequest2.CookieContainer.Add(webResponse.Cookies[1]);
            myWebRequest2.CookieContainer.Add(webResponse.Cookies[2]);
            myWebRequest2.CookieContainer.Add(webResponse.Cookies[3]);


            StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(myWebRequest2.GetRequestStream());
            string json = "{ \"type-id\": 3,\"name\": \"MyPrueba\"}";

            streamWriter.Write(json);
            streamWriter.Flush();
            streamWriter.Close();

            webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myWebRequest2.GetResponse();
```

I get the error in the line `webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myWebRequest2.GetResponse();`

Comment: "400" is an HTTP error, which is returned by the server at "myURL". So it depends on what that web service expects, and how that differs from what you're sending.

Comment: you should create ONE CookieContainer and assign that to every webrequest you execute. The way you copy cookies here is a recipe for failure. Also install a local proxy, like fiddler so you can debug the http requests.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the [Create an Entity documentation](http://alm-help.saas.hpe.com/en/12.53/api_refs/REST_TECH_PREVIEW/Content/General/Create_an_Entity.html), there are some problems with JSON structure that you are trying to send.

This structure

```
{
  "Fields":[{
      "Name":"type-id",
      "values":[{"value":"3"}]
    },{
      "Name":"name",
      "values":[{"value":"MyPrueba"}]
    }]
}
```

should be used instead of this one

```
{
  "type-id":3,
  "name":"MyPrueba"
}
```